# The java right implemantion of equals?

Tags: java

i try to find out what is the right way to implement java equals.
reading on the net I saw that there are many Thoughts on the subject I narrow down to 2 options
1 using instance of and on using getClass() != obj.getClass()
to follow the rules of :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)
this is my final result :

```
public class Foo {
private List<Long> days;
private String project;
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        //avoid symmetry problem
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Foo test = (Foo)obj;
 
        return equals(this.project,test.project) && equals(this.days,test.days);
 
    }
 
    public static boolean equals(Object a,Object b) {
        return a == b || a != null && b!=null && a.equals(b);
    }
}
```

what do you say ?

Comment: That static `equals` is not needed. [`Objects` already provides it.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object))

Comment: Using == to compare the classes is a bit suspect because often time there are subclasses that you would want them to be equal. I would suggest [isAssignableFrom](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) with Foo that will handle a wider range of cases.

Comment: I recommend [reading through this](https://ahdak.github.io/blog/effective-java-part-2/) which is based on the recommendations given by Joshua Bloch in his Effective Java books

Comment: @matt or even simpler, just use `!(o instanceof Foo)` which also includes the null check

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good in general. `getClass() != obj.getClass()` is sufficient enough. It will only fail for positive scenario if someone goes crazy with tricky custom code to load same class with different classloaders.

I would also replace your custom equals on fields with standard `Objects.equals` at the end:

```
        return Objects.equals(days, foo.days) &&
                Objects.equals(project, foo.project);
```

Comment: " if someone goes crazy with tricky custom code " it isn't too crazy to have different classloaders. Also any sub classes would fail.

Comment: I meant loading the same class by different loaders, not sharing some parent one - it is hard to imagine such use case. Agree that it is possible though. Failing subclasses - depends on the logic, by default I would expect instanceOfSubclassA.equals(instanceOfSubclassB) to return false.

Comment: @udalmik i dont follow you what you say that is good to have another method to 
that using instanceOf and call it instanceOfSubClass ?

Comment: no no, it was about getClass() != o.getClass() giving false for different subclasses, which is a equals valid result in general cases

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to override hashcode when you override equals too.
You may want to custom the equals on the list if the order matter.

```
  @Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Foo foo = (Foo) o;
    return Objects.equals(days, foo.days) && Objects.equals(project, foo.project);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(days, project);
}
```

Comment: how is the hashCode related to the equals ?

Answer (score -1):

You would rewrite your code with the following consideration, we use equals() to compare objects otherwise, = sign used to compare data types